# Sony Qx 10 - camera trigger control via the USB connection

Tags: sony

I wish control the trigger of a Sony Qx10 camera with an USB cable connected to a PC or an Arduino.

It is to make photographs every 3 seconds when Sony Qx10 in a UAV far from me.

Is this possible and how must I do?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the Sony Camera Remote API SDK:

https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/

Control is done via WiFi however, not over USB.

Comment: Not, I do not think that it is possible because the API of Sony use a Wifi connection and me, I would like to use a USB connection.

Comment: Right, as I mentioned above USB is not supported.  Is there a reason you can't use WiFi?  The API itself is http/JSON based so it is platform independent so the only issue would be connecting by WiFi.

Comment: Marlin - most radio control links to the UAVs use 2.4GHz, the 2.4GHz wifi can interfere with the 2.4 signal used to control the UAV

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, usb is not supported sony remote apis. So you can use on wifi.(Because only supported http protocol)
It is possible but different ways. I thing you should include wifi shields or like a nodemcu board. (Actually, boards of supported http protocol)

You should looking for this site: [NodeMCU](http://nodemcu.com/index_en.html#fr_54745c8bd775ef4b99000011)

I am working on sony qx1 remote control. If I finished the project, I will upload on github. Have a nice day.
Sorry my language.